# can i reach a main class variable, by using the value of an external class property

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok so my problem is this.

In my main class I have a Boolean type variable. In the external class I have a String type variable.

Is it possible to access the variable in my main class, by using the string value of the variable in my external class. Note that the string value of the external class property matches the main class variable.

I just tryed doing this:

Main class CardGame.as has a variable `var slot1:Boolean`.

In the external class there is the variable `var slot:String = slot1;`
I also have this line of code: `CardGame['slot'] = false;`

It doesn't seem to be working :( . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Part of the main class file:

```
function drawCard():void
    {

        var card:Card = new Card();
        if(slot1 == false)
        {
            card.x = 30;
            slot1 = true;
            card.slot = "slot1";
        }
        else if(slot2 == false)
        {
            card.x = 190;
            slot2 = true;
            card.slot = "slot2";
        }
        else if(slot3 == false)
        {
            card.x = 350;
            slot3 = true;
            card.slot = "slot3";
        }
        else if(slot4 == false)
        {
            card.x = 510;
            slot4 = true;
            card.slot = "slot4";
        }
        else if(slot5 == false)
        {
            card.x = 670;
            slot5 = true;
            card.slot = "slot5";
        }
        else
        {
            card.x = 830;
            slot6 = true;
            card.slot = "slot6";
        }
        card.y = cardY;
        cardContainer.addChild(card);
    }
```

And the external file:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import CardGame;

public class Card extends MovieClip
{
    public var slot:String;

    public function Card()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeCard)
    }

    function removeCard(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        CardGame['slot'] = false;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a few lines of code in the external class:

```
// in CardGame.as

// declare slot1 as a public var right after the class declaration to insure the 
// correct scope

public class CardGame extends MovieClip {

     public static var slot1:Boolean;

     ....

// in external class
import CardGame // depends on where this is in relation to the external class

function theFunction():void {
    // somewhere in your external class
    var slot:String = CardGame.slot1.toString();
}



// Example classes that show how it works
// Main Class - instantiates ExtClass
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MainVar extends Sprite {
        public static var slot1:Boolean;
        private var extClass:ExtClass;

        public function MainVar() {
            slot1 = true;
            this.extClass = new ExtClass();
        }
    }
}

// External Class accesses static var, modifies static var
package {
    public class ExtClass {
        public function ExtClass() {
            var slot:String = MainVar.slot1.toString();
            var index:String = "1";
            var slotVar:String = "slot" + index;
            trace(slot);
            // get the value using a string
            trace("String access: ", MainVar[slotVar])
            MainVar.slot1 = false;
            slot = MainVar.slot1.toString();
            trace("Var access: ", slot);
        // get the value using a string
            trace("String access: ", MainVar[slotVar]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. If I'm not getting this wrong, what you suggest would assign the slot1 variable from the main class as a string value to the variable in the external class. However what I'm looking for is to change the Boolean value of the slot1 variable on the main class by trying to reference it from the external class using the String value of the slot variable there. I hope that makes sence. And yes the Boolean variable in the main class is a public var, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: this wouldn't work anyway: `slot1` would have to be `static` to be accessed this way.

Comment: 32bitkid, I just changed slot1 to public static var. Still not working :(. Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: @Zdravko - fixed the code - added the static and changed the 'as String' with .toString() and it works on a test swf I just made.

Comment: and if you don't want to use static there are other options - you can pass a reference to CardGame to the external class and modify things that way.  If you want to go with that, I'll adjust the code.

Comment: @Gone3d, please excuse me if I am not reading this correctly. What you suggest would assign a new String value to the `slot` variable in the external file, using the `public static var slot1` as a string, right? What I'm looking for is to change the Boolean value of the `slot1` variable. I am trying to reach it from the external class by using the String value of the variable `slot` there. The variable slot already has a Value, that was assigned from the main class, before the discussed code takes place. This string value is already set to 'slot1'.

Comment: @Zdravko - updated the code to show how I changed the value in the external class - the trace on this code was true, false

Comment: Thank you for your work again. While this works perfectly well, it doesn't suit my purpose. You see, there are six (slot1, slot2, slot3..) Boolean variables in the main class. That is why I need to reference one of them depending on the String value of the `slot` variable in the external class. Otherwise I would have just referenced the var directly by using `MainClass.varName`, instead of trying to use a string. I will update my question with more of the actual code.

Comment: I've expanded the answer - I think it is now what you are looking for